# Nutch 2.3+Gora+Hbase : Strange Values Parsed

Tags: nutch

I have started playing around with Nutch2.3+Gora+HBase, but the some  results look strange in HBase, is there any configuration or a simple step I might be missing?

```
status: value=\x00\x00\x00\x01
fetchTime: value=\x00\x00\x01L\x93\x92\x0F\x5C
prevFetchTime: value=\x00\x00\x01L\x91]\xF5\x1C
```

Expected values should be:

- status: 4
- fetchTime:  1426888912463  (i.e. in timestamp format)
- prevFetchTime:  1424296904936  (i.e. in timestamp format)

Why am I getting the actual values instead of the expected ones?

Comment: Do you have problem with all of these records in Hbase or just with some of them? I meant all of status, fetchTime and prevFetchTime values.

Comment: all of status, fetchTime and prevFetchTime values in all records in HBase.

Any idea how to resolve it?